# Updating React Component State after Axios Call using Redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm working to learn React and Redux. As part of this, I'm creating a simple app that retrieves a list of items from my REST API. To query this REST API, I'm using Axios. Currently, I do not understand how to actually update the state in the store. The Redux examples are confusing.

At this time, my app has the following:

```
/my-app
  /actions
    items.js
  /components
    items.js
  App.css
  App.js
  index.css
  index.js
  store.js
```

**/my-app/actions/items.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

export GET_ITEMS = 'GET_ITEMS';

export const getItems = (count) => {
  axios.get('https://my-app.com/items')
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response.results);
      // need to set "response.results" to the value in the store
    }
};
```

**/components/items.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import { getItems } from '../actions/items';

class Items extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: []
    }
  }

  onButtonClick = () => {
    getItems(5);
  }

  render() {
    return {
      <div>
        <button type="button" onClick={this.onButtonClick}>Load Items</button>
        <br />

        {this.state.items.map((item) => {
          <div>{item.name}</div>
        ))}
      </div>
    }
  }
}
```

**App.js**

```
import React from 'react';

import Items from './components/items';

function App() {
  return {
    <div>
      <Items></Items>
    </div>
  };
}

export default App;
```

**/store.js**

```
import { createStore } from 'redux';

import { GET_ITEMS } from './actions/items';

let initialState = {
  items: [
    {
      id:1,
      name:'Item A',
      description: 'This is a pre-populated item for testing purposes.'
    }
  ]
}

function itemsReducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_ITEMS:
      break;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}

let store = createStore(itemsReducer, initialState);
export default store;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import store from './store';

import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

When I run this, I see a screen with a button. I can click the button, however, I do not see the items displayed on the screen. If I look in the console window, I can see the items printed via the `console.log` statement.

How do I take the items returned from the REST API and a) set those items in the `store` and b) use the store items in my component?

Thank you so much for your help! Redux has been a challenge.

Comment: read https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk and https://react-redux.js.org/

Answer (score 0):

To make things easy, I will keep this folder structure

```
/my-app
  /API
    index.js
  /state
     action-types.js
    /actions
       items.js
    /reducers
       items.js
  /components
    /items
       ItemComponent.js
```

I like to separate my API from state to offer better separation of concerns/control

**API/index.js**

```
import axios from 'axios';

const BASE_URL = 'https://my-app.com/items';

export const getItems = () => {
  axios
    .get(`${BASE_URL}/items`)
    .then(response => response.data)
    .catch(error => error);
};
```

**Reasons I like this approach**

- this allows call to `getItems` API endpoint without calling `getItems` action and state update
- In case you decide to use any different API library in place of `axios`, you don't need to modify all your action files

**action-types.js**

```
  export const GET_ITEMS = 'GET_ITEMS';
```

**/actions/item.js**

```
import * as ACTION_TYPES from '../action-types';
import * as API from '../../API';

const getItems = async count => {
  const getItemsResponse = await API.getItems();

  return {
    type: ACTION_TYPES.GET_ITEMS,
    payload: {
      items: getItemsResponse.data,
      count
    }
  };
};

export default getItems;
```

**/reducers/item.js**

```
import * as ACTION_TYPES from '../action-types';

const initialState = {
  items: [
    {
      id:1,
      name:'Item A',
      description: 'This is a pre-populated item for testing purposes.'
    }
  ]
}

const itemsReducer = (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTION_TYPES.GET_ITEMS:
      const { items } = action.payload;
      return { ...state, items }
      break;
    default:
      return state;
  }
}
```

Lastly, you can wrap `connect` from `react-redux` around the `ItemComponent.js`. The code below should be added to what already exist in the file
**ItemComponent.js**

```
const mapDispatchToPtops = {
    getItems
}

const mapStateToProp = state =>({
   items: state.itemsReducer.items
})

export default connect(mapStateToProp, mapDispatchToPtops)(ItemComponent)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. However, I'm still confused how this maps to the "store". There doesn't seem to be a store in your answer.